# How can I make the Material UI mobile menu to start from the leftmost part of the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image: Here's a screenshot with the issue]

I am designing the UI for a web app I am working on with React and Material UI for the mobile orientation. I have been trying to get the sidebar menu to appear starting from the leftmost part of the screen, and there seems to be some sort of margin that won't let the left part of the menu start from the left edge. It starts a few pixels after. What can I do?

Here's a piece of my code for reference:

```
<Menu
    className='menu-style'
    anchorReference="anchorPosition"
    anchorPosition = {{top: 90, left: 0}}
    anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left'}}
    transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'left'}}
    anchorEl={null}
    open={isOpen}
    onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
    PaperProps={{
        style: {
            width: '80vw', 
            margin: '0 !important',
            height: '100vh',
        },
    }}
>
    <MenuItem onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
        <a href='#'>Buy</a>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I have tried setting the margins to 0 with the paper props style but it's not responding to it. The dropdown menu still starts a few pixels after the left, instead of from the leftmost part. No parent components have any margins added to them either.

Comment: It will help if you create a codepen or something so people can see the problem that you are trying to describe. Even screenshots will help.

Comment: I just posted a screenshot link. Thanks!

Comment: In your PaperProps, can you try adding left: '0px !important' . Not sure if you need important, but try with and without it.

Comment: I just tried that, it's still stuck in its position. Do you think the anchorReference may be causing the issue?

Comment: Can you please post what change you tried in PaperProps when you added left: 0px ?

Comment: I tried your code change and it appears like some material ui code is making sure the menu does not disappear off the edge off the screen and does not appear too much at the edge. I used anchorEl to make it appear at the top left. It does appear at the top left but then automatically moves 16px off the top and left.
If the position is non-negotiable, your best option is the open a paper yourself in that position and implement a simple menu there.

Answer (score 0):

Would a `Drawer` be a better component in your use case?

With that aside, you can use the `sx` prop or the `styled` functionality combined with the provided class definition `menuClasses` to position the menu statically.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import { menuClasses } from '@mui/material';

export default function PositionedMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>
      <Button
        id="demo-positioned-button"
        aria-controls={open ? 'demo-positioned-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Dashboard
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="demo-positioned-menu"
        aria-labelledby="demo-positioned-button"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        sx={{
          [`& .${menuClasses.paper}`]: {
            left: '0 !important',
          },
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `!important` is required as you are fighting `popper` which is attempting to dynamically position your menu by assigning `left` and `top` as a direct style.